# how to convert XML to JSON in java?

Tags: java, xml, json

How to convert XML to JSON in java servlet.

```
    <?xml><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:HNS="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><HNS:ROClientID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">{6C9A8E69-2018-4090-8FA7-DEB98300E102}</HNS:ROClientID></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ro="http://tempuri.org/"><NS1:GetStationListResponse xmlns:NS1="urn:WOOSServices-WOrbitService"><Stations xsi:type="xsd:string"></Stations><Result xsi:type="xsd:string">{
    "MOColmns": [
        {
            "MOTitle": "Description"
        },
        {
            "MOTitle": "station_name"
        },
        {
            "MOTitle": "StationID"
        },
        {
            "MOTitle": "StationINT"
        }
    ]
}</Result></NS1:GetStationListResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
            String xml = "<xx yy='nn'><mm>zzz</mm></xx>";

            JSONArray json = (JSONArray) XMLSerializer.read(xml);  
            System.out.println( json );
```

please help me.

Comment: Any reason why the answer is not accepted? :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can grab a set of Java classes to handle JSON at http://json.org/java/

There you can find the XML and JSONObject classes, among others.  This code could work for you:

```
public String XMLtoJSON(String xml) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    String json = jsonObj.toString();
    return json;
}
```

Comment: In @antur123's answer, I believe all instances of "string" should be "String", in which case that code should work.

Comment: @selladurai Any reason this is not selected as the answer?

Comment: Excellent observation, @RajeevM, :-)

Comment: Hi antur123, I can't able to handle XML.toJSONObject(xml) because i can able to resolve XML, how can i resolve this? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import org.json.XML in your class to resolve XML. Or Put org.json.XML to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) can convert xml to json.

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

String xml = "<xx yy=\"nn\"><mm>zzz</mm></xx>";

String json = U.xmlToJson(xml);  
System.out.println(json);
```