# Accessing JSON object inside Message Stanza using Smack Library

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging, stanza

my addAsyncStanzaListner is being called when an ack message is received from Firebase Cloud Messaging services. I need to ack this messages according to the docs. The problem that I am having is I can't reach the "message_type" "key"/"value" pair inside the JSON object that arrives inside the message stanza that's received. Could you please help me in accessing this important value/pair. I am using Smack Library 4.1. I've been following this post answer for this setup, but somehow It doesn't work: 
***[GCM XMPP Server using Smack 4.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056939/gcm-xmpp-server-using-smack-4-1-0/30093856#30093856)***

Here's how the code is looking like:

```
other_connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
@Override
public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws    SmackException.NotConnectedException {
//how should i convert this stanza into a message stanza
//I have tried Message message = (Message)packet;   IT DOESNT WORK
//I have tried getting the extension with the GCM Namespace. It doesnt
//return a json string
```

Comment: Since you are using the smack library, have a look at this sample which uses smack 4.1. https://github.com/googlesamples/friendlyping/blob/master/server/Java/src/main/java/com/gcm/samples/friendlyping/SmackCcsClient.java#L111

Answer (score 0):

In your code you just recive a Stanza as Java Object.

Stanza has a method to output an XML.

You can use this method to obtain a JSON if you need, just add some custom functionality.

[Following this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724263/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java)

your code can looks like this:

```
@Override
public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws    SmackException.NotConnectedException {
    JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(packet.toXML());
    String json = jsonObj.toString();
//foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is for the general problem of extracting JSON from a message. In the case of FCM, it's possible that there's another method that's more appropriate.

Suppose your have a `Stanza` object that corresponds to the following XML:

```
<message from='a@example.com' to='b@example.com' type='normal'>
    <json xmlns='urn:xmpp:json:0'>{ "key1" : "value1", "key2": "value2" }</json>
    <body/>
</message>
```

To extract the JSON string, you need to do:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.json.packet.JsonPacketExtension;
...
JsonPacketExtension jsonPacketExtension = JsonPacketExtension.from(stanza);
String contentJson = jsonPacketExtension.getJson();
```